# Creating Hibernate criteria on two field together with like query

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Assume that I wanna query on both name and surname of users with "like". Both field are seperated as two column in database. How can I query with like as start mode(like abc%),  Here is sql query code;

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("from UserAccount where name || ' ' || surname like '" + fullName + "%'");
```

How to do that with criteria?

Thank!

Comment: Is there no solution? please help!

Comment: "is working on DB2 but PostgreSQL" what did you get when running it against postgresql?

Comment: I tried one more time and there is no problem for PostgreSQL now. But I could not find to do that with criteria yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserAccount.class)
    .add(Property.forName("name").like("abc"))
    .add(Property.forName("surname").like("def"));
```

Instead of `Property.forName()` one could use `Restrictions`. For example: `Restrictions.like("name", "abc")`.

Comment: This wont help making criteria on two column together. This one is  query on two field as separated. This one just helps to query name_field==name% and surname_field==surname%. I need to query name_field+surname_field==(name+surname)%